# How do I loop through a column and check if the value matches the next value then append?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am attempting to loop through a column. If the the item in the column matches the next item in the column. If they are the same, I will take values associated with the first row item and append it with stuff from the lines below.

I have tried using nested if loops to loop through a column. Ignore some of the functionality my code, but I am not sure why my comparisons are not working.

```
For bigLoop = 1 To Length + 1
    firstString = Workbooks("VBA_Basics.xlsm").Worksheets("TestSheet").Cells(bigLoop, 24).Value
    Cells(bigLoop, 28).Value = Cells(bigLoop, 26)
    Debug.Print firstString
    
    
    For smallLoop = 1 To Length + 1
        secondString = Workbooks("VBA_Basics.xlsm").Worksheets("TestSheet").Cells(smallLoop + 1, 4).Value
        
        
        Debug.Print secondString

        myComp = StrComp(firstString, secondString, vbBinaryCompare)
        If myComp = 0 Then
            Cells(bigLoop, 28).Value = Cells(bigLoop, 26).Value & " :) " & Cells(smallLoop + 1, 26).Value
        End If
        
        Debug.Print myComp
    Next smallLoop
Next bigLoop
```

Comment: You have a mixture of explicit worksheet references and implicit ActiveSheet references.  It might be that you are not comparing the cells you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

Please sort your column! Then try this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Const NITEMS As Integer = 11
' Column "A"
Private Const COLUMN As Integer = 1
' Column "B"
Private Const TARGET_COLUMN As Integer = 2

' Please sort your column!
Public Sub X()
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim V1 As Variant
Dim V2 As Variant

   I = 1
   While I <= NITEMS
      V1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(I, COLUMN).Value
      ActiveSheet.Cells(I, TARGET_COLUMN).Value = V1
    
      J = I + 1
      V2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(J, COLUMN).Value
      While V1 = V2 And J <= NITEMS
         ActiveSheet.Cells(I, TARGET_COLUMN).Value = _
                      ActiveSheet.Cells(I, TARGET_COLUMN).Value & " :) " & V2
         J = J + 1
         V2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(J, COLUMN).Value
      Wend
      
      I = J
   Wend
   
End Sub
```